# Using id from array in dynamically generated form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to dynamically generate a form from a database so that I can simply login and make changes, as well as track the votes. The form is generating fine but, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the id from the array to post in with the data. The only successful attempt set the last one as all of their topic_id because I tried to define it in the while statement.

```
  <?php  $cat_set = fetch_categories();

  if (!isset($business_name)) {
  $business_name = ''; }

    while($categories = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_set)) {
                echo '<div class="category">'. "<h3>" . "Best of the Best"      
   .' ' . ucfirst($categories["cat_name"]) . ' ' . "</h3>";

                $topic_set = get_topics_for_cat($categories["cat_id"]);
                    while($topics = mysqli_fetch_assoc($topic_set)) {
                        $topic_name = $topics["topic_name"];
                    echo '<div class="field">' . '<label for=' . 
  $topics['topic_id'] . '">' . ucfirst($topic_name) . ":" . '</label>';
                        echo '<input type="text"' . 'id="' . 
  $topics['topic_id'] . '"' . 'name="'
                        . $topics["topic_id"] . '"' . 'value="' . 
  $business_name . '"></div>';
                    }
                    echo "</div>";
    }
    ?>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submitform"></form>
</div>
<pre>
<?php
$user_id = 3000;
if (isset($_POST['submitform'])) {
    print_r($_POST);

foreach ($_POST as $business_name) {
    $filtered_business_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,  
$business_name);
    $query = "INSERT INTO votes (";
    $query .=" business_name, topic_id, user_id";
    $query .= ") VALUES (";
    $query .=" '$filtered_business_name', '$topics['topic_id']',   
'$user_id'";
    $query .=")";

    $votes = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

So more specifically I guess, what would be the best way to get $topics['topic_id'] into my query? I've tried to escape it and about everything I can think of.

Comment: I need it to get the topics from the topic table, and reference their individual topic_id in the table with the votes ...

Comment: Use type='checkbox' and set value=$topics['topic_id'] and you'll be in better shape

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. uhm, no it's an annual contest that the local newspaper has, and I need it to be easier to manage, so each user will get their id from the users table, once that's set they can access this form, each topic has a topic id, not shown to the user but, used to reference which topic they've voted on. From the Topic_set it's $topics["topic_id"] and I just need that to write into the query so that I can tell what they're voting on.

There doesn't need to be a unique id or anything as they can vote multiple times.

Comment: I thought about using Radio buttons Chris but, after looking at last years there are literally hundreds of different businesses that they're voting on. I started building out the businesses table and realized that it just wasn't feasible.

Comment: As a textbox, they will be able to change the value.  I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: They should be able to enter their own value. I just need the $topics['topic_id'] in the query WITH what they typed. So the $_POST with the id.

Comment: Remember only name and value are sent back with the submit.  Change the name to "<input .....   name=\"topic[{$topics['topic_id']}]\" and php will create an array for you that you can $key=>$value

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: Thanks tadman, I don't know anything about any of that. I'll try to get it though, sometime ...

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the variable in curly brackets:

`$query .=" '$filtered_business_name', '{$topics['topic_id']}', '$user_id'";`

Comment: That didn't do anything.

Comment: Print out the query before execution and see if it looks right. Also check to make sure the type of the data you're inserting matches the type of the table column. You've enclosed both `$topics['topic_id']` and `$user_id` in single quotes indicating data of type string. Is that intentional or are they supposed to be integers?

Comment: $query .=" '$filtered_business_name', '{$topics['topic_id']}', '$user_id'";

returns
INSERT INTO votes ( business_name, topic_id, user_id) VALUES ( 'a', '', '3000')Database query failed.

They'd both be integers, wouldn't it juggle them while inserting? I don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

```
 $topic = $topics['topic_id'];
$query .=" '$filtered_business_name', '$topic', '$user_id'";
```

Comment: It's outside of the loop though, so the value for all the topics just ends up being the last value of $topic_id. I tried that when I first broke it.

Comment: Wow, now I see. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I must have just been using it wrong. I'd made so many edits and things that my own stuff didn't make sense, so I reversed a bunch and tried the key=>value thing ... and it worked right off. Now the query is:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitform'])) {

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $filtered_business_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $value);
    $query = "INSERT INTO votes (";
    $query .=" business_name, topic_id, user_id";
    $query .= ") VALUES (";
    $query .=" '$filtered_business_name', '$key', '$user_id'";
    $query .=")";

    $votes = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    confirm_query($votes);

}
}
```

Thank you everyone for your help, hopefully this will help someone with their crappy form building in the future.